# Extract with reg exp

Tags: regex, sed, uri

I have a fair amount of Image Search results, which I want to convert to a fair amount of actual images.

All results are HTML pages for a single image, and every file contains the substring

> <title>Google-Ergebnis für [uri]</title>

where [uri] denotes the absolute URI of the actual result image (http://...(.gif|.jpg|.jpeg|.bmp)).

But I don't get it how to extract the uri to hand it over to wget.

> cat imgres.html | grep "<title>" | sed 's/<title>Google-Ergebnis für http://(.*)</title>/\\1/'

Comment: I don't know much about `sed`, but both in `http://` and `</title>` you're using `/` which is also your regex delimiter - can you do this? Shouldn't you escape them as `http:\/\/` and `<\/title>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close on your sed command:

```
 sed -n 's#<title>Google-Ergebnis für \(http://.*\)</title>#\1#p' imgres.html
```

No need for cat, grep, and multiple pipes though.

Answer (score 2):

grep should help in this case:

```
....grep "<title>"|grep -Po "(?<=Google-Ergebnis für )[^<]*"
```

test

```
kent$ echo "<title>Google-Ergebnis für http://foo.bar.baz/blah.png</title>"|grep -Po "(?<=Google-Ergebnis für )[^<]*"
http://foo.bar.baz/blah.png
```

**Note**  actually, you could combine the two grep into one.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I am assuming your issue was how you'd pass on what you extracted from grep/sed to `wget`.

```
cat imgres.html | grep "<title>" | 
  sed 's#<title>Google-Ergebnis für \(http://.*\)</title>#\1#' |
wget -i -
```

Slightly more compact:

```
sed -n '/<title>/{s#.*<title>Google-Ergebnis für \(http://.*\)</title>.*#\1#;p}' imgres.html | 
  wget -i -
```

Note the use of `#` ins place of the usual `/` as the delimiter for `s`.

Comment: Why are you concatenating imgres.html with nothing and then having grep operate on the result rather than just having grep open the file?

Comment: Laziness?  :-) Yes, I've heard of the 'useless use of `cat` award ;-)' But felt too lazy to mess with the OP's original code. But thanks for pointing out.